# VB/SQL - How To Filter DataGridView From Joined Table With Multiple Matches

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm using SQL Server and Visual Studio 2019.

I'm looking for advise on the best way to filter my documents list (in DataGridView) based on what view they appear in.

I have 3 database tables shown below:

[image: Tables]

I have simplified my **Document table** for this post, but there is quite a lot of details for each document displayed in the **DataGridView**.

I fill a **DataTable** which I use to apple into a **DataView** which is then used at my **DataGridView** **DataSource**.
Within the **SQL** that fills the **DataTable** I have a *custom column* that uses a **JOIN** to determine the **View** that each document appears in, I later then filter the document list based on the *custom column*.
This only really works if the document only appears in 1 view, as otherwise the **JOIN** retrieves multiple entries of the document to cover each **View** matched. (hope that makes sense).

I have simplified the **View table** for this post also, a **View** can contain **Sub Views** if you like i.e.:

```
View 1
 > Sub View 1
 > Sub View 2
    > Child of Sub View 2
```

This means a **Document** can appear more than once in a **View** as it may appear in various **Sub Views**.

I'm wonder if I'm best to carry on retrieving the **Custom Column** or if I should be running a whole new **SQL** query and even creating a new **DataTable** / **DataView** based on the **View table**.

Some of our workers are remote and some projects can contain thousands of documents, so I want to ensure I used the most robust method, but also one that will cause the least delay on retrieving the information and give the user the best experience.

I hope I've explained everything enough for you guys to get the list of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance and I would appreciate any help on this.

```
>
>
Edit - Following first answer post:
```

As you say I probably haven't explained enough, so I've put together a visual example of what I'm trying to achieve.

When a project is loaded all documents are listed, the **TreeView** hasn't been clicked so *no filter* is applied. All documents are listed:

[image: View 1]

If a user clicks "**View 1 > Sub View 2**" on the **TreeView** it *filters* based on the data in **CustomJOINColumn**, see below:

[image: View 2]

If a user clicks "**View 1 > Sub View 1**" or "**Another View > Documents**" on the **TreeView** it again *filters* based on the data in **CustomJOINColumn**, see below:

[image: View 34]

As you can see **Document D001** has appeared in *3 different views/sub views*.

The problem is shown in the first image. **Document D001** is listed 3 times as it is associated with 3 views/sub views.
I only want **Document D001** to *appear once in the first list*, but when the corresponding **Node** in the **TreeView** is clicked it *filters* correctly as shown.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I added a section to my answer to address your update to the question, I don't know if SA notifies you when an answer is edited but I know they do when a comment is added so I'm commenting too

Answer (score 0):

There might be some details of your case that indicate a different solution, but from what you have here it sounds like you should drop the special column, drop the full-fill with filtering, and implement a focused fill for your DataGridView. It doesn't even involve much of a change, a slight modification rather than a major rewrite.

Why? Because especially if you have remote workers on a WAN, the performance hit of loading the full list of documents will be crushing if you have many large views. A focused load allows you to spend time loading only the relevant document details. You get the first 500ms or so "for free" with users, but if you take even 30 seconds to load and filter they'll think it's crashed. And your application takes more memory when it's stuffed full of grid rows of document details you'll never use. Plus, as you've already discovered, coming up with a filtering scheme based on membership in an arbitrary number of overlapping groups is really hard, and a focused load is really easy.

So how to do it?
First, go to your DataSet and modify the table adapter with "Add"->"Query". You'll define a new query that uses a parameter (@View) and returns data in the same format as the original, but only for documents in that view. Give it an obvious name, like when it offers a name "Fill" make it "FillByView"

Next, grab a copy of the code in your Form_Load event that fill the grid (something like tadaptDocs.Fill(tblDocList)) and comment it out there, but place a copy in the Change event for the control that the user selects the view in. Change it from "Fill" to "FillByView" and add the @View parameter.

You'll probably want the Form_Load event to set the view to the last View chosen (save in My.Settings) or the first view in the list, that will kick off a Change event and populate the DataGridView with an initial set of documents.

Now, every time the user picks a new view, the grid is loaded with just those documents in that view, regardless of what other views they may be in.

When you save the changes via "Update", VB automatically applies the changes to the underlying data, you don't have to worry that it will truncate your database table to just the documents in that view. It makes an internal distinction between records that were deleted and records that were never loaded. You also don't need to make new versions of the Update, Insert, or Delete methods on the TableAdapter, only Fill Needs a new version that considers View.

EDIT: The following added in response to additions made clarifying the problem

It sounds like a focused load is still called for, but only when the user selects a view. Your initial view should be a "fill all", but modified to strip duplicates. If you have many details in the grid you'll probably want to break that out into 2 parts with a CTE, example follows

```
;WITH cteCust as (
   SELECT D.DocID as DocID, D.docNum , D.docTitle , V.CustJoinName as CustJoin
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.docNum ORDER BY V.viewTitle) as ViewRank
   FROM #tblDoc as D  LEFT OUTER JOIN #MapDocView as M on D.DocID = M.DocID
        OUTER APPLY fnGetCustJoinName(M.ViewID) as V 
) SELECT C.DocID , C.docNum , C.docTitle , C.CustJoin , D.docOther 
FROM cteCust as C INNER JOIN #tblDoc as D ON C.DocID = D.DocID 
WHERE ViewRank = 1
ORDER BY D.docNum
```

A few elements of this bear explaining, reply in comments if you need more details

**cteCust** extracts the core document info and adds the custom join columns, I'm not sure how you're doing it, but a table valued function is one way and I used it for simplicity, substitute whatever you're using. You said there was a lot of document info, this lets you work with just the core details and tie in the other stuff later. We're using a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** on the Map table because you want docs without a view to still show up in the unfiltered list.

**ViewRank** is how you get rid of duplicates, by partitioning a ROW_NUMBER function over the Documents, you get only the first view it's in. In the focused fill you want the view filtered on, but you said the initial fill should be just one view so each document appears only once.

Note that the final SELECT ties it back to the Documents table so you can pick up the extra fields.

**NOTE:** In your example you have a simple membership model - you want Docs that belong to a specific view not a hierarchical one where you want all docs in a view and all sub views (i.e. D006 is in *Approved* but does not show up when you select the parent *Documents* in example 3 of your updated question). If those requirements change and your customers want a recursive membership scan, you should post it as a second question, this Q&A is already huge and you'll get fresh eyes on it if it's a new question. Post a reference here too, but make it a new question.

Comment: Robert, thank you for your response. As you say I may not have detailed enough about the operation of my program. Please see my original post edit. Thank you.